# My code is failing a test due to time limit restriction, how do I decrease the time taken by my code to work?

Tags: c++, algorithm, while-loop, time-complexity, modulo

Question - You are given two positive integers a and b. In one move you can increase a by 1 (replace a with a+1). Your task is to find the minimum number of moves you need to do in order to make a divisible by b. It is possible, that you have to make 0 moves, as a is already divisible by b. You have to answer t independent test cases.

Input -
The first line of the input contains one integer t (1≤t≤10^4) — the number of test cases. Then t test cases follow.

The only line of the test case contains two integers a and b (1≤a,b≤10^9).

Output -
For each test case print the answer — the minimum number of moves you need to do in order to make a divisible by b.

Code Forces question link - https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1328/A

Time Limit - 1 second per test case

My code -

```
int main(){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
 
    long long t,a,b,x;
    cin >> t;
    for(long long i=0;i<t;i++){
        cin >> a >> b;
        x = a;
        while(a%b!=0){
            a++;
        }
        cout << a-x << endl;
    }
}
```

It is failing when the number of test cases is 10000 and there are big input numbers. What can I do to decrease the execution time of my code?

Comment: Find the algorithm they want you to use. Modulo is likely what's holding you back.

Comment: Think about it. If you know `(x-1)%y`, do you need to start from scratch to compute `x%y`? If you were asked how many times this code would loop for large input numbers, how would you directly compute how many times it would loop? Hint: If `a%b` isn't zero but is, say, 4, what does that tell you?

Comment: Hint: 13%4 = 1, 14%4 = 2, 15%4 = 3, 16%4 = 0...

Comment: Can you give me $19.91 using ten-dollar bills? no.  Can you give me $19.92 using ten-dollar bills? no Can you give me $19.93 using ten-dollar bills? no. Can you give me $19.94 using ten-dollar bills? no.  Can you give me $19.95 using ten-collar bills?  No.  Can you give me $19.96 using ten-dollar bills?  Can you give me $19.97 using ten-dollar bills? no. Can you give me $19.98 using ten-dollar bills? ... _Do you see the inefficiency of what you're doing yet? Can you predict what the first value you will answer "yes" to will be?  And how did you compute it without counting?_

Comment: Please have a look at the tutorial ([link](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/75246)) provided by the problem author.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got it

Answer (score 1):

You need to find m such that a + m = kb with 0≤m<b (you want the next multiple). If we divide the equation by b, we have (a + m)/b = k, which is also k = ceiling(a/b).

So m = ceiling(a/b) b - a.